# Kotlin Elvis Operator failing on JsonElement?

Tags: android, kotlin, null, operators

I have this gson JsonElement I am attempting to parse. It's possible that certain attributed of this json element do not exist, so I am attempting to use an Elvis Operator to provide a default value (empty string) in the case that parts of the json element do not exist. Here is the json element that is giving me trouble:

```
{"und":[{"value":null,"format":null,"safe_value":""}]}
```

What I am attempting to do is extract 'value' from this as a string. If it's null, then I want to default it to an empty string.

Here is how I am going about this (*note: this json element is called `phone`*):

```
val tempPhone = phone?.asJsonObject?.get("und")?.asJsonArray?.get(0)?.asJsonObject?.get("value")?.asString ?: ""
```

I broke this down step by step to debug, and here is what my debugger is showing (*note: debugger logs in `()`*):

```
var undArr = phone?.asJsonObject?.get("und")?.asJsonArray   debug: (undArr: "[{"value":null,"format":null,"safe_value":""}]")
var undObj = undArr?.get(0)?.asJsonObject   debug: (undObj: "{"value":null,"format":null,"safe_value":""}")
var value = undVal?.get("value").   debug: (value: "null")
var valueString = value?.asString ?: ""
```

The error is occurring on the last line. From my understanding of the Elvis Operator, if `value` is `null` then `var valueString = value?.asString ?: ""` should simply set `valueString` to an empty string. Instead what is happening is an exception gets thrown.

Is this not the proper implementation of the Elvis operator? I'm a little confused at why it's failing.

Comment: I don't know what Json library you're using, but what's probably happening is `asString` casts to String, but `value` is not a String...it's some other kind of object.

Comment: I'm using the GSON library as stated in the question. Also, isn't that the whole point of the Elvis Operator: to provide a a default if an operation is not possible?

Comment: It provides an alternate value if the current value is null. Nothing more. It won't catch exceptions.

Comment: but the current value is null. That's where I'm confused... In my code above, `value` is null, therefore it should fall to the Elvis Operator

Comment: Ah, I missed that. If that's the case, `asString` should never be called. There is almost certainly something you copied incorrectly above or you misinterpreted about whether `value` is actually null.

Comment: I believe it is. It should be considering it's null (not "null") in the json. And even if it is "null", then `asString` should work perfectly fine because then it is a literal string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at Gson's source code, a null value in your Json is represented as a JsonNull object, not an actual `null` value in Java or Kotlin.

JsonNull does not support calling `asString` on it. It will throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

So your `value` is most likely not `null`, but rather an instance of JsonNull. So `value?.asString` calls `JsonNull.getAsString()`, which throws UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Wow. What a strange way to handle null.